# One line if statement in R - invalid first argument

Tags: r, object, if-statement, exists

I'm writing simple code in R where I'm checking whether given file exists in the working directory and if it doesn't I'm downloading zip file with the data and unzipping it in R. As it happens, if the file exists the R objects corresponding to binary (**getBinaryURL**) and connection to the file are connected. I would like to remove them after successful download. I drafted those one sentence if statements but they return error **Error in exists(bin) : invalid first argument.** It's intermediately obvious to me what's wrong with the syntax.

```
if (exists(bin)) rm(bin)
if (exists(con)) rm(con)
if (exists(dataurl)) rm(dataurl)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `if()` statement isn't the problem, you need to quote the object passed to `exists()`.

```
> AnObject <- seq(1:10)
> exists(AnObject)
Error in exists(AnObject) : invalid first argument
> exists("AnObject")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand that I don't have to quote the object in the **rm** statement?

Comment: @Konrad That's correct. The majority of functions take an object's unquoted name rather than quoted; the best thing to do when you use a new or unfamiliar function and get an error is to check its help file for more information. If you type `?exists` you can check how the object is specified in the "Arguments" section, as well as see examples of how it is used at the bottom of the page.